# How to make my frontend and backend to communicate with each other in Angular?

Tags: angular, frontend, backend

I am new to web development and was wondering **how I can make a frontend angular project communicate with a backend** angular project.

- I want to send user input to my backend.
- I also want my backend to send information to my frontend to display.

Comment: Http client service? Call enpoint of your server. Perhaps if you are very nzw to dev, check firebase.

Comment: I heard something about koa, would that be a possible way of doing it?

Comment: angular is a frontend framework. Not sure how you'd be able to even use it as a backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to send and receive data form your backend in angular app.

#### Getting Data in angular:

1. create a service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

2. create function to get data in service

```
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}
```

3. call function inside your component

```
showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = {
        heroesUrl: data['heroesUrl'],
        textfile:  data['textfile']
    });
}
```

#### Sending data to the server

1. Adding headers

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

2. Making a POST request

```
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

3. Call a service post method on form submit or click inside component

```
this.heroesService
  .addHero(newHero)
  .subscribe(hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
```

for more details, please go through angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) guide.